# format numeric string in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a data in the following format

> "1214423-034"

in html table, How can I format the string such that I only display everything after hyphen, so in this case only display "

> 034"

Is there any html function that I can use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by HTML function, or how do you expect HTML to do something like this.

Comment: Is this just static HTML or are you building it dynamically (C#, js, etc.)? I'm assuming dynamic in some way, in which case what you are looking for is substring or its equivalent.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I have a strongly-typed view with output as I described above which I want to format. I am using ASP.NET framework with c#

Comment: @user793468 I am quite sorry, but how could we know what technologies you use? There are dozens of programming languages used to generate HTML. After asking more than 100 questions, you should know how to ask.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I thought I had tagged those, just checked, and I forgot to tag. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string foo = "1214423-034";
        Response.Write(foo.Substring(foo.IndexOf("-") + 1));

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this easily with Javascript using the [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) and [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) functions, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "1214423-034";
    var pos = str.indexOf("-");
    document.write(str.substring(pos + 1));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
e.g. <div id="lblText" >1214423-034</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = $("#lblText").text().split("-");
});
</script>
```

Incase you decide to do in C#

```
string text = "1214423-034";

text = text.split("-").[1];

int number = 0;

bool result = Int32.TryParse(text, out number);
```